# SQL Server Secure Communication

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, ssl

I am designing a C# application that will comunicate with na SQL Server for data keep/fetch.
This app is supposed to be used from within AND without the local network where the server will be (ie accross offices or even countries) so communicastion with the sever needs to be done over the internet.

I have setup a few tests and everything works well but now it's time to add security into the design.

With connections coming from the internet into their servers, my clientes will want the communication between the cliente app and the SQL server to be as safe as possible from net sniffers and such (ie, keep people from listening in to the data being transfered or worse, get server access)

I have read somewhere some time way back (can't find the link anymore) that SQL Server has na option for SSL connectio.

So my question is - Is this my best or even only option for security? Where can i find information/code samples on how to implement this?

Before anyone goes there - i have googled this but got no luck beyhond the information that an SSL connection option exists.

Comment: Is a VPN an option? Or have you considered a webservice for interacting with the database (and having your application only interact with that over SSL, or otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a good article on SQL server security best pratices, it covers operative instructions and code examples.
[Microsoft SQL Server Security Best Practices](http://www.greensql.com/microsoft-sql-server-database-security-best-practices/)

I think that you have a bigger issue here with your application design though. How are you deploying and updating your apps? You probably want to have a server-side data access layer, possibly have business logic located on the server in a single location. I'd be looking at using WCF, possibly azure and web services with a thin client application.

Comment: wow - lots of info there - great link - will also look at the links provided by Paul but at first glance this seams like the most complete answer so Paul gets a +1 and you an answer mark

Comment: WCF is something i am also looking into - just not sure yest on the all install process since i only made small local tests with wcf - it's making an install that just works cliente side for the non tech clients to be on the clear that worries me on this - but i am looking at it

Answer (score 2):

Look into setting up encryption at the server using ssl and setting Force Protocol Encryption. Have a read of [How to enable SSL encryption for an instance of SQL Server by using Microsoft Management Console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898)

Also read this [Enable Encrypted Connections to the Database Engine (SQL Server Configuration Manager)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#ConfigureServerConnections)